# pass Session string to sql as uniqueidentifier

Tags: c#, session, casting, guid

I have a session variable which holds a guid string:

```
Session["Company_Id"] = "4B5E95A7-745A-462F-AE53-709A8583700A";
```

I want to pass this as a parameter to SQL Server:

So add the parameter:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Company_Id", System.Data.SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = Session["Company_Id"];
```

When the Stored Procedure gets called I get:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Guid.'

Appreciate any guidance ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Company_Id", System.Data.SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = Guid.Parse(Session["Company_Id"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as `Guid` by using `Guid.Parse` method which would be convert your `string` representation of your `Guid` to `Guid` :

```
Guid.Parse(Session["Company_Id"].ToString());
```

Your command code would become:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Company_Id", System.Data.SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = Guid.Parse(Session["Company_Id"].ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks Ehsan. This answer is excellent and it has moved me on a little but not quite there yet. When the Stored Proc executes it still is not returning matching (well I think matching) data. If I put a default value on the SQL then I get data back i.e:

        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter dbType="guid" Name="Company_Id" defaultvalue="4B5E95A7-745A-462F-AE53-709A8583700A" />
        </SelectParameters>